# Does 'apply camera image' not work for OpenEXR camera background images?

Tags: texturing, camera, image, error

I Recently started using Meshroom to photoscan buildings. While  the raw Meshroom output is hardly ever usable directly (with my cheap camera anyway), does provide an extremely nice basis for modeling the building.

You can import the camera-reconstruction and the resulting pointcloud into  blender and use that as as base for your model.

The nice thing is, you can even project the original photo's back onto your handcrafted low-poly model and you can get very nice results that way.

Meshroom outputs it's remapped images (with camera distortion compensation) in OpenExr format. I can open these and use them as camera backgrounmd images in Blender, and they show up just fine.

When I select 'apply camera image' when texture Painting nothing happens, the camera background images does not get projected on the model.

The strange thing is: if I convert the OpenExr image to JPG or PNG and use that as a camera background image it suddenly *does* work.

Does anybody know if this is a bug? Or is there something extra I need to tweak somwhere to get this to work? I'd very much like to  skip the extra conversion step as all those images are taking a lot of HD space.

I did try various color space settings for the camere background image, but none have any affect on the projection (but the background images does get rendered differently depending on the colorspace).

I  understand this is a highly specific question, but I hoped maybe someone else happens to use the same Meshroom->Blender workflow.

regards...

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Applying an EXR  as camera image works in my system. Do you have a blank image as texture to receive the projected image?.

Comment: can you share an image  to test?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fum34xhtcsyjwrt/IMG_0546.JPG-reprojected.exr?dl=0 This image does show up as a camera background image, but it won't appear on my painted texture when doing 'apply camera image'. And yes, I do have a (blank) image to receive. Converting this exact same image to JPG (with imagemagick) and using that instead makea it show up on my texture. (While it looks exactly the same in the blender vieport)

Comment: something about that particular EXR is off. I can apply any other EXR image, but not the one you upladed.

Comment: Strangely if i open the EXR in blender and save it again as EXR then the copy can be applied correctly on top of the geometry. I would explore if Meshroom has some settings that can be changed to export EXRs. The difference between the original and the copy in blender is the compression scheme used, the one from Meshroom is compressed using half float and **piz** compression , try a different compression scheme or going full float.

Comment: Note that you don't really have to export EXRs, out of meshroom, you can choose other formats as well on the Export Animated Camera node.

Comment: I used the exrs from the PrepareDenseScene. I'll look into export settings from Meshroom, thanks. Still..., isn't it strange that the image displays correctly in Blender, but then refuses to apply? Even stranger just now, after some 'camera applying' from an other (jpeg) image, the exr image suddenly does 'stick' on some faces, but not on others. Anyway, I'll explore exr settings from Meshroom.

Comment: I looked into meshroom and there are no options for the EXR format. It might indeed be a bug, but I don't know if it is on blender or meshroom. Since you are using jpegs as originals anyway you are not really gaining anything by using EXRs other than being in a visually lossless format. Try PNGs, horrible format, but it at least will allow you to stay lossless as well. Maybe it is worth filing a bug report both on blender and Meshroom.

Comment: I'll research some more, and then maybe file a bugreport. Thanks for the help